# How to execute max tasks on backend without starting a new instance - Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a set of tasks and I want to run them on backend. I want to cap to max 2 instances. Is there a way to execute maximum number of tasks without creating another more than the maximum tasks?

I want to execute maximum permissible tasks keeping the max to 2 instances. I cannot cap the task rate as some rate takes a second and some can take 20 seconds to finish.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of instances that you want in [backends.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Java_Types_of_backends):

```
<backends>
 <backend name="memdb">
   <class>B8</class>
   <instances>2</instances>
 </backend>
</backends>
```

Or you can switch from backends to modules. Then you can choose a scaling method and set the maximum number of instances, if you select Basic Scaling.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Comment: This sets the maximum instances but how do we ensure that it's using the entire available CPU. How does appengine scheduler determine when do stop giving it more tasks?

Comment: The best you can do with backends is to make them dynamic. If you want more control over scheduling, you need to use modules.

Comment: The problem with scaling is not an issue but how do we know how many parallel tasks can it take?

Comment: You can run tests on instances of different sizes.